# Generalized linear mixed effects model in java

Tags: java, r, machine-learning, statistics

I have a R code which uses glmer method for creating generalized linear mixed effect models and I need to port this code to java.

Is there a library which provides this functionality out of the box?

I tried google and so but could find anything directly useful.

Is there a way to implement mixed effect regression using Apache Math library?

I am still learning the concepts of mixed effect model and do not fully understand the concepts yet. I found a class here which provides multiple regression, http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/regression/MultipleLinearRegression.html and i think i might be able to use it implement what I need.

Has anyone tried doing something similar before?

Comment: You could take the easy solution and interface R from Java using the rJava package.

Comment: could you provide link to the rJava package you are talking about?

Comment: Added an example as answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You could use the rJava package. It requires that R is installed on the machine, however, it allows then to call R code from java.

To use it you need to first install it `install.packages('rJava')`.
Afterwards you need to add the following to directories to R

```
<R_HOME>\bin\i386;
<R_HOME>\library\rJava\jri\i386;
```

in java you need to add all jars from

```
<R_HOME>\library\rJava\jri
```

to your class path.

Afterwards you can call rJava

```
Rengine eng = new Rengine(new String[] { "--no-save" }, false, null);

String[] colNames = {"col1", "col2", "col3"};
String[] col1 = {"a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"};
String[] col2 = {"b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"};
int[] col3 = {1, 2, 3, 4};

REXP mydf = REXP
            .createDataFrame(new RList(
                    new REXP[] {
                            new REXPString(col1),
                            new REXPString(col2),
                            new REXPInteger(col3)},
                    colNames));
//generate a dataframe inr engine
eng.assign("myDataFrame", mydf);

 //Calculate MEAN of vector using R syntax.
 eng.eval("meanVal=mean(myDataFrame$col3)");

 //Retrieve MEAN value
 double mean = eng.eval("meanVal").asDouble();
```